# How to get Python WebJob working on Azure

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk-python

I am struggling to deploy a Python WorkerRole on Microsoft Azure.  Has anybody successfully gotten a Python process working on Microsoft Azure?

Microsoft seems to be telling people that their documentation related to Python on Azure is out of date, see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-python-ptvs/#comment-2790110068 and https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/1447.

A Microsoft employ told me that I need to install my own Python interpreter when I deploy a WorkerRole.  Does anybody know how to do that?

My worker.py file consists solely of `$print("in the worker".format(datetime.now()))`

after I deploy the WorkerRole the following error is in both the ConfigureCloudService.err and LaunchWorker.err.

```
gi : Cannot find path 'E:\approot\%INTERPRETERPATH%' because it does not     exist.
At E:\approot\bin\ConfigureCloudService.ps1:189 char:15
+ Set-Alias py (gi $interpreter_path -EA Stop)
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (E:\approot\%INTERPRETERPATH%:String) [Get-Item], ItemNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetItemCommand
```

Comment: Your link is to something related to worker roles, nothing to do with Web Jobs. No clue who you're referencing (@zooba) and why anyone would be suggesting deploying a python interpreter (since that is *not* required). Meanwhile... you've shown nothing about what you've tried - you simply posted a question asking if anyone has gotten a python web job working. As it stands, this question will likely be closed.

Comment: Yeah, I got WebJob and WorkerRole confused.  I am trying to deploy a WorkerRole.

Comment: @DavidMakogon, I modified my question.  Is that information helpful?

Answer (score 0):

@andrewkittredge, I don't think you need to install Python environment manually before deploying a WorkerRole or a WebJob, because the Python runtime has been installed on Azure, just need to be specified or set up in the related configuration.

According to the [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-python-ptvs/), you need to create a workrole via VS with PTVS. Then, `Install Python on the cloud service` means you need to set the Python variable to `on` on the startup tasks in the `ServiceDefinition.csdef` file as below.

```
<Variable name="PYTHON2" value="on" />
```

Please see the article [Common Cloud Service startup tasks](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-startup-tasks-common/) to know the startup tasks for Cloud Services.

Compared with `WorkerRole`, I think `WebJobs` is easier to use and deploy, please see the articles [Run Background tasks with WebJobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/) and [Deploy WebJobs using Visual Studio](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs/).

Comment: According to the updated documentation @ https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-python-ptvs/ you do need to install Python.  I eventually got my worker role going with that updated documentation.

In theory WebJobs look like a good solution.  But I ran into two problems.  I couldn't get the WebJob Python to run in 64 bit mode I tried changing the application platform setting to 64 bit but the WebJob interpreter was still in 32 bit mode.  Also I couldn't get Numpy working in a WebJob.  I tried using a wheel but I ran into the upload size limit on WebJobs.